# Why does this proof involving the FTOC "work"?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$.
>   Define $F(x) = \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t) dt$. Calculate the derivative $F'(x)$.

First I simplified the problem a bit. If $G(x) = \int_{\gamma}^{x} h(t)dt$ for some $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and we want to calculate $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{\gamma}^{g(x)} h(t) dt$ we can use the fact that this expression equals $G(g(x))$. Thus we get $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{\gamma}^{g(x)} h(t) dt = \frac{d}{dx} G(g(x)) = g'(x)\cdot G'(g(x)) = g'(x)\cdot h(g(x))$, where the last equality is due to the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Now, to solve the actual problem I just assumed that $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then there exists an $\gamma \in [f(x), g(x)]$ and we can write

$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} F(x) &= \frac{d}{dx} \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(t) dt = \frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_{f(x)}^{\gamma} h(t)dt + \int_{\gamma}^{g(x)} h(t)dt \right)\\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \left( -\int_{\gamma}^{f(x)} h(t)dt + \int_{\gamma}^{g(x)} h(t)dt \right)\\
&= -\frac{d}{dx} G(f(x)) + \frac{d}{dx} G(g(x))\\
&= -f'(x)\cdot h(f(x)) + g'(x)\cdot h(g(x)) 
\end{align}$

So, ... I reduced the problem to the special case I considered beforehand and at least WolframAlpha arrives at the same solution (hah!). However, I don't know how to prove the result when $f < g$ doesn't hold (who knows how $f,g$ will behave? maybe $f > g$ will hold for some intervals while $f < g$ will be true for others).

What is a clean way to prove the result? Can my proof be salvaged?

Comment: You don't need to assume $f(x) > g(x)$; $\gamma$ can be any real number. FTOC does not require the upper-limit to be greater than the lower-limit and $\int_a^b = \int_a^c + \int_c^b$ holds for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (given that the function we integrate is defined over the values we integrate over).

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to refresh some of these concepts  $\ddot\smile$

Comment: No problem. Other than that issue (which is fixed by just removing the assumption and fixing $\gamma =0$ for example) your proof is good.